# variable is not defined inside http request in node and express

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

In my express action `get('items')` I'm calling an external JSON-API and would like to render the API response in my local response.

Currently I get an error that my items variable is not defined inside of the http request. It seems this is a scope issue but I didn't find a solution.

What is the best way to accomplish this?

```
var http = require('http');

router.get('/items', function (req, res, next) {
    var items;

    var RemoteRequest = http.request({
        method: 'GET',
        path: 'myurl'
    }, function (response) {
        response.on('data', function (data) {
            items = JSON.parse(data);
        });
    });

    RemoteRequest .end();
    res.render('new', {items: items} );
    // or res.json({items: items});
});
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to return the response from an asynchronous call?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: res.render is getting called before the http request has a chance to get a response.  You should put the res.render in the response.on(... function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you are not waiting for the return from your http request, you need to move the `res.render('new', {items: items} );` into the callback:

```
var http = require('http');

router.get('/items', function (req, res, next) {
    var items;

    var RemoteRequest = http.request({
        method: 'GET',
        path: 'myurl'
    }, function (response) {
        response.on('data', function (data) {
            items = JSON.parse(data);
            res.render('new', {items: items} );
            // or res.json({items: items});
        });
    });

    RemoteRequest .end();
});
```

Comment: Sometimes it works but sometimes I get `unexpected end of input`

Comment: well now you have a completely different problem not appropriate to this question... try and resolve it and if you cannot post a new SO question.